# convert enums in Protobuf to enums in c#

Tags: c#, enums, protocol-buffers

I have this proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

message AdminIpoChange
{
 string Id =1;
 string SymbolName =2;
 string SymbolIsin =3;
 string Date =4;
 string Time=5;
 double MinPrice =6;
 double MaxPrice =7;
 int32 Share =8;
 bool Show =9;
 AdminIpoOperation Operation =10;
 string  CreateDateTime=11;
enum AdminIpoOperation
{
    Add = 0;
    Edit = 1;
    Delete = 2;
}

}
```

And here I have this class

```
 public class AdminIpoChangeEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        public AdminIpoChangeEntity()
        {

        }
        public string SymbolName { get; set; }
        public string SymbolIsin { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public double MinPrice { get; set; }
        public double MaxPrice { get; set; }
        public int Share { get; set; }
        public bool Show { get; set; }
        public AdminIpoOperation Operation { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }



        public enum AdminIpoOperation
        {
            Add = 0,
            Edit = 1,
            Delete = 2
        }
}
```

So I want to convert the operation enum in proto to enum in c# as you can see :

```
        public static AdminIpoChangeEntity Map(AdminIpoChange adminIpoChange)
 => new()
 {
     
     CreateDateTime=DateTime.Parse(adminIpoChange.CreateDateTime),Date=adminIpoChange.Date,MaxPrice=adminIpoChange.MaxPrice,    
     MinPrice=adminIpoChange.MinPrice,Operation=adminIpoChange.Operation,Share=adminIpoChange.Share,Show=adminIpoChange.Show,
     SymbolIsin=adminIpoChange.SymbolIsin,SymbolName=adminIpoChange.SymbolName,Time=adminIpoChange.Time,
 };
```

But in this part `Operation=adminIpoChange.Operation`I get this error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'AdminIpoChange.Types.AdminIpoOperation' to 'domain.Entities.AdminIpoChangeEntity.AdminIpoOperation'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    domain  D:\****\domain\Entities\AdminIpoChangeEntity.cs 43  Active
```

Comment: Just cast from one to the other, as the error suggests.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks like this ?Operation=(AdminIpoOperation)adminIpoChange.Operation

Comment: Yup, that should do it.

Comment: Just as an aside, do you have a particular reason to have a C# class that's a mirror of the .proto message? One would normally just use protoc to generate c# code from that .proto and use the generated class. I've had to do that kind of thing when bridging between serialisation systems (e.g. between GPB and ASN1). Even then it's possible to use reflection in C# to automatically match up members in the classes generated by the different serialisation technologies, saving writing code like MinPrice=adminIpoChang.MinPrice.